# Filtering an expression output with regexp

Tags: scheme, read-eval-print-loop, guile

The bad code of main is `(string-match "module" (help uri-path))` that returns an error

```
scheme@(guile-user) [5]> (string-match "module" (help uri-path))
`uri-path' is an object in the (web uri) module.

- Special Form: uri-path

While compiling expression:
Syntax error:
unknown file:9:23: sequence of zero expressions in form (begin)
scheme@(guile-user) [5]>
```

What I am trying to reach, is displaying only one line of help function output. How to fix it?

Comment: `help` is *printing* the help, not returning it as a string.  You would have to understand the implementation of `help` to somehow capture the output as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`procedure-documentation`](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Procedure-Properties.html) to get the documentation of a procedure as a string.

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (help cons)
`cons' is a procedure in the (ice-9 safe-r5rs) module.

- Scheme Procedure: cons x y
     Return a newly allocated pair whose car is X and whose cdr is Y.
     The pair is guaranteed to be different (in the sense of `eq?') from
     every previously existing object.
```

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (procedure-documentation cons)
$6 = "- Scheme Procedure: cons x y\n     Return a newly allocated pair whose car is X and whose cdr is Y.\n     The pair is guaranteed to be different (in the sense of `eq?') from\n     every previously existing object."
```